# Django One-To-One and One-To-Many Relations

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model, foreign-keys

I am trying to implement the following data model in a Django app:

A Project consists of 3 containers:
1) Actionable
2) References
3) Backburner

An Entry can be created within a project and needs to be assigned to either of the containers (it cannot remain free-floating).

Hence, a Project always contains the three containers, any of which can be empty. An Entry is always in one (and only one) of the containers. However, an Entry can be switched from container to container.

Here is my attempt. Is this at all reasonable?

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')

class References(models.Model):
    project = models.OneToOneField(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

class BackburnerItems(models.Model):
    project = models.OneToOneField(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

class ActionSteps(models.Model):
    project = models.OneToOneField(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_steps = models.ForeignKey(ActionSteps)
    references = models.ForeignKey(References)
    backburner = models.ForeignKey(BackburnerItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `CharField` with choices to assign an entry to a specific container:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    REFERENCE = 'reference'
    BACKBURNER = 'backburner-item'
    ACTION_STEP = 'action-step'
    CONTAINER_CHOICES = (
        (REFERENCE, 'Reference'),
        (BACKBURNER, 'Backburner item'),
        (ACTION_STEP, 'Action step'),
    )
    container = models.CharField(choices=CONTAINER_CHOICES)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

You can easily query for entries belonging to a specific container, either from a `Project` instance or from the `Entry` class:

```
references = project.entry_set.filter(container=Entry.REFERENCE)
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to ensure that containers are created when a project is created? Or should I only create a container for a project if an Entry is about to be moved there?

Comment: The container is no longer a separate model, it is simply a char field in the `Entry` model, with the `Entry` having a `ForeignKey` directly to the `Project`. There's no need to create the containers separately.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: When I go to make migrations for this implementation, I get the following warning: `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'project' to entry without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py`

Comment: How could I include a default?

Comment: The warning is from this line: `project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`